# How to overload a template function to match specific containers?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following function to retrieve the `n` element of a container - `O(n)`:

```
template<typename Container>
const typename Container::value_type& getNthElement(const Container& container, size_t n) {
    auto itr = cbegin(container);
    for (auto i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        ++itr;
    }
    return *itr;
}
```

And for `vectors` I have this overload - `O(1)`:

```
template<typename T>
T getNthElement(const vector<T>& container, size_t n) {
    return container[n];
}
```

Now if I wanna use a deque (which also has the `O(1)` implementation), the first template function will be called with the `O(n)` implementation.

How can the second overload function be adapted to works for `vectors` and `deques` ?
My question is taken from [this](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/247153-type-dependent-code-reuse-part-1-the-basics) article.

Comment: Lookup [template specialization](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dtemplate%20specialization)

Comment: I want only one function to be used for both containers, I am not sure how can I do with template specialisation to match both of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple approach is to tag-dipatch based on the iterator category, i.e., something like this:

```
template <typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
nth_element(It begin, It end, std::size_t n, std::input_iterator_tag) {
    for (std::size_t i(0); it != end && i != n; ++i) {
        ++i;
    }
    return it != end? *it: throw std::runtime_error("out of range");
}
template <typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
nth_element(It begin, It end, std::size_t n, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
    return n < std::size_t(end - begin)? it[n]: std::runtime_error("out of range");
}
template <typename C>
typename C::value_type
nth_element(Container const& c, std::size_t n) {
    return nth_element(c.begin(), c.end(), n,
                       typename std::iterator_traits<C>::iterator_category());
}
```

If it weren't for `n` possibly being too big, you could actually just have `std::advance()` do the trick:

```
template <typename C>
typename C::value_type
nth_element(Container const& c, std::size_t n) {
    auto it = c.begin();
    std::advance(it, n);
    return *it;
}
```

With C++11 extended SFINAE you can sniff-out whether this capability is available even without traits.

Comment: Or even `return *std::next(c.begin(), n)`;

Comment: @Barry: all this new stuff introduced with C++11 keeps catching me out...!